# How does a for loop allow redeclaration of a variable?

Tags: c#

This:

```
int j = 1;
int j = 2;
Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());
```

.. produces a compile error:

> A local variable named 'j' is already defined in this scope

Yet this works fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  int j = i;
  Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());
}
```

Why?

How does the loop simultaneous retain values from each iteration whilst being able to redeclare a variable with the same name in the same scope?

Comment: dude refer concept of scope global and local

Comment: The key here is _already defined in this scope_. The loop defines it's own scope.

Comment: Learn about variable scope

Comment: The easiest way to describe this is: `int foo = 1;` is making a declaration _and_ assignment.  And we all know you cannot declare a variable with the same name in the same scope which is what you are doing in your first example.  The second example is fine because you aren't making a second declaration, your `j` variable is only declared once in scope (the loop "resets" the scope on every iteration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable  `j` exists only per iteration, i.e. in each iteration a variable `j` is declared, assigned, used and then discarded and the next iteration begins and the process repeats and so forth. hence you don't get the same compilation error as the first example snippet.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `int j=1` and `int j=2`, you are *trying* to declare the variable twice (you can only declare it once).

You could, however, overwrite the value of `j`:

```
int j = 1; // now j has a value of 1
j = 2; // now j has a value of 2
```

This is what the `for` loop is doing - each iteration of the `for` loop, the value is updated.  A new instance of `j` is not created during each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are defining two variables with the same name, and they exist at the same time.

In the loop, every variable is created in the loop context. After each iteration the variable is destroyed, allowing you to create a new one with the same name(on the next iteration). In other words, on the loop they don't exist at the same time.